Probability - Average Streak Length
How do you calculate the average streak length given a known, exact probability for an infinite number of tries?
To give a concrete example, let's say I have a single fair die, and I want to roll sixes. The probability of getting a six is 1/6; the probability of rolling another six is still 1/6, as the previous result does not change the odds; and so on until eventually you don't roll a six and the streak is broken. What's the average streak length of rolling sixes in a row (assuming you always start with a six roll, and dismiss 0 streaks as irrelevant)?

X is the streak length, X=1,2,...
p is the streak probability, is constant
q=1-p, is the probability of streak ending
$ \mu_X$ is the average
$p_X(x)=qp^{x-1}$
By definition $\mu_X=\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}x \ p_X(x)=\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}x \ qp^{x-1}=
q \sum_{x=1}^{\infty}xp^{x-1}=q(\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}p^x)'=q(\frac{1}{1-p})'=q(\frac{1}{q^2})=\frac{1}{q}$
Note :
$ \sum_{x=1}^{\infty}xp^{x-1}=\frac{d \ (\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}p^x)}{dp}=(\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}p^x)'$
because it is a geometric series $\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}p^x =\frac{1}{1-p}$
In the dice example, average streak length would be 1/(5/6) = 1.2, that is right.
In the dice example,
The rolls stop when 6 does not come up
x=1 means that the first roll of the die did not come up 6.
x=2 means that the second roll of the die did not come up 6, this means that the first roll came up 6.
...

What does $x$ mean? What does $q$ mean? What does $p$ mean? Too moch unexplained notation – very low quality answer.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

So if I'm understanding correctly, in the dice example, average streak length would be 1/(5/6) = 1.2?

OK, now I know what $q$ and $p$ mean, but $x$?

If I understand the question correctly, it is equivalent to asking for the expected value of the number of die throws needed before a number other than a $~6~$ is thrown.
Let $~f(n)~$ denote the probability of throwing exactly $~n~$ 6's followed by a number other than $~6.~$
Then, $~f(n) = 5 \times \dfrac{1}{6^{n+1}},~$ and so the expected value of the number of $~6$'s thrown is
$$\frac{5}{6} \times \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n}{6^n} \tag1.$$
Using the formula that for $~|x| < 1$:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^n = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2},$$
the expression in (1) above becomes
$$\frac{5}{6} \times \frac{1/6}{25/36} = \frac{5}{6} \times \frac{6}{25} = \frac{1}{5}.$$
Edit
I re-worded the problem to (in effect) omit the first die throw, that the original poster assumes to be a $~6.$
If this die throw is re-instated, then, as indicated by the comment of Nic, the average number of 6's thrown becomes $~1 + .2 = 1.2$

Might be helpful to note that this is the average number of sixes thrown after the first six and hence the average streak length is $1+1/5 = 1.2$.

@Nic After thinking some more about your comment, I re-considered.  I have edited my answer to accommodate your comment.
